# IE 10 Width Issue with Absolutely Positioned Child

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, internet-explorer-10

I have this issue where the child extends past the parent. The child has percentage width and is absolutely positioned. I created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/f2zf7par/

```
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
   <table class="child"><tr><td>test</td></tr><tr><td>test</td></tr>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>

.grand-parent {width: 100%; max-width: 400px; height: 300px;  background: #000;}
.parent {
 width: 100%;  position: relative;}
.child {background: #fff; width: 50%; height: 50%;position: absolute; right: 0;}
```

How can I have IE behave the same way as other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Instead `right:0`, you can do this:

```
left:50%;
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2zf7par/1/

It is basically the same, right, and look the same in IE (11, hopefully 10, too), Chrome and Firefox.